# Getting CORS error in .net core 5.0 while calling from cross url

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-core-5.0

I am getting following error of CORS

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44385/AuctionDetails/GetAllAuctions' from origin 'https://localhost:44341' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I am trying to WebAPI developed in .Net Core 5.0 from another application.

My ajax call is as below :

```
 $.ajax({
            async: true,
            url: "https://localhost:44385/AuctionDetails/GetAllAuctions",
            type: "GET",
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: "JSON",
            headers: {
                "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + '@Session["USRT_TOKEN"]',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
            },
            success: function (responseData) {
                console.log(responseData);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert("Failure");
            },
            error: function (errorMessage) {
                debugger;
                console.log(errorMessage.statusText);
                if (errorMessage.status == "401") {
                    if (errorMessage.responseText == "") {
                        alert("Invalid Token. Please login again.");
                        RedirectToLogin(errorMessage.responseText);
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Invalid Token. Please login again.");
                    }

                }
                else {
                    alert(errorMessage.responseText);
                }
            }
        });
```

I have installed Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors package. And have make following changes in Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();
        **services.AddCors(options => options.AddDefaultPolicy(
            builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()));**
        services.AddControllers();
    }
```

And have added app.UseCors() between app.UseRouting() and app.UseAuthorization().

I have also tried this with policy, but still having same issue. My API code is also called, but after having response also it's falls in error section of ajax call.

After trying all this, I am not getting idea why it's happening like this.

Comment: Any idea you found a solution, getting a similar issue where the calls are working from controller but AJAX call is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Also try adding release rules for headers and methods. Like:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder => 
    {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
        builder.AllowAnyHeader();
        builder.AllowAnyMethod();
    }));
```